# Hiding and showing dividers using javascript - Works in JSFiddle, doesn't work on site

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a small javascript to hide dividers when the value of a dropdown menu has changed.
But for some reason the script doesn't work on my own site.

```
document.getElementById("type").onchange = function () {
    var v = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    if (v == 1) {
        document.getElementById("CostDiv").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("CostDiv").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Here's a link: http://jsfiddle.net/WeHv3/

Answer (score 0):

is there more than one element in the html document called CostDiv ?

Please give us the source of the html document as that is only difference at the moment I can see.

Comment: Seems like the problem was a missing jQuery CDN, I've been wasting my time for hours on this.

Comment: Welcome to programming!, always check the obvious!

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is your listener are unable to attach with your element.

Just add your JavaScript at the bottom of page and your problem is solved.